# Justification with even space between words and after punctuation

Tags: spacing, justification

I'm writing a book and I'd like to have the text justified. Nevertheless, I notice the spacing between words and after punctuation is different (red short, blue long). Is there a simple fix for this? (I read similar questions but the solution doesn't seem to apply to my case).

[image]

I think the relevant code for this part is this one:

```
\usepackage[german,russian,hungarian,spanish,czech,english]{babel} %I use different languages in the copy
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

Comment: `\frenchspacing`

Comment: Off topic, but proper German would probably rather be "das Metallband, das an der Wand hing".  The past tense (Präteritum) of the verb "hängen" is formed regularly only when the verb is used transitively, but not when it is used intransitively, as far as I know.